How to run python script on login
I am attempting to load a python script that launches a Firefox Geckodriver under Selenium whenever a specific kiosk user logs in to the GUI.
I've tried launching this via .profile, however geckodriver throws an error "Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified". I've tried loading this from .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .xsession (not used in my case) with little luck. The browser will launch with the line in .bashrc, but only when a terminal is opened manually and not when the user logs in graphically.
How do I launch this python script on login for this user with the display environment it needs?

I was able to fix this issue by configuring the following:

Open a terminal on the user you'd like to configure this for and create a ~/.config/autostart/kiosk.desktop in a text editor (nano ~/.config/autostart/kiosk.desktop). You may need to create the autostart directory in .config as well.

Within the kiosk.desktop file input:


[Desktop Entry]
Name=<AppName>
Type=Application
Exec=python3 /path/to/script/init.py

Now when that user logs into their desktop, this script will automatically trigger within the graphics environment.
